# Getting the month number from a given month name

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find the corresponding month number from a given month name.  What the easiest way of achieving this is?

Comment: What are your criteria for "easiest"? Do they include cross–browser, robust, maintainable, correct?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is not really a need for jQuery in this case.

JavaScript along these lines might help:

```
var monthNumber = ["january", "february", "march"].indexOf(monthname.toLowerCase()) + 1;
```

Expand the array with all months to make it fully functional.

Answer (score 5):

Simpler method to give a value from 0 (January) to 11 (December):

```
var monthString = 'December';
var dat = new Date('1 ' + monthString + ' 1999');
alert(dat.getMonth());
```

Comment: for human-readable, I'd just say `alert(dat.getMonth() + 1);`

Comment: Not sure it's a good idea to rely on implementation dependent parsing of a non–standard string.

Comment: There is no standard or specification indicating that a string in that format should be correctly parsed by the Date constructor. ECMA-262 says [parsing of non–standard strings is implementation dependent](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.4.2). The fact that it "works" in the few browsers you tested doesn't mean it works everywhere. Other answers are at least based on basic ECMAScript functionality that can be expected to work everywhere with a fair degree of certainty.

Comment: Ok, well it works in IE, Chrome, FF and Safari. Good enough for me! If you find somewhere it doesn't work, I'd be interested to hear about it.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to `Array.prototype.indexOf` is an object:

```
var months = {jan: 0, feb:1, mar:2 ...};
var monthName = 'January';

var monthNum = months[monthName.substring(0,3).toLowerCase()];
```

The advantage is that you can accept various forms of the month name such as Jan, jan, JAN, January, JANUARY, etc.

Oh, the above assumes you want month number as for a javascript Date constructor input. To get calendar month number, just increase the values by 1.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need JQuery because this can be solved by javascript easily.

Use Key Value pair like following

```
var months = {jan:1, feb:2, mar:3, apr:4, may:5, jun:6};
```

You can get month number easily by calling month name like following

```
months.jan  // will return 1 to the caller
```

or

```
alert(months.feb); //will shows 2 in message box;
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on where this information is coming from you might be interested in using a library called DateJS:

- http://www.datejs.com/

It doesn't use jquery but it is good at parsing dates. If you look in the downloads section it also contains 150+ internationalised libraries if you need to handle foreign language input.

Answer (score 1):

The way i would do it is like this

Make an array with all months;

```
var data=new Array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December")

//Lets say you get this back from your get month function. This should return january, because that is the first month..
var numberOfMonth = 1;

//An array starts with the index 0, so you could do minus 1 to get the correct one

alert data[numberOfMonth - 1]);
```